# Vuetify create 2 related v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Are there any ways onchange Alist v-select, base on Alist item to ajax, and apply the result to Blist items looping? That is what I have done for the integration. But it shows: `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "items"`

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
<td>
    <v-select style="width: 250px" :items="Alist" label="Purchase Order" @change="updateBlist(index, $event)"></v-select>
</td>
<td>
    <v-select style="width: 250px" :ref="'Blist'+index" :items="Blist" label="Group Tasks"></v-select>
</td>
</tr>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        Blist: [],
        Alist: [],
    },
    methods: {
        updateBlist(index, value) {
            // Get Group Task List
            axios
                .get("/api/Blist/list/" + value)
                .then((resp) => {
                    this.$refs.[`Blist${index}`][0].items = [];
                    _.forEach(resp.data.data, (value, key) => {
                        var tmp = {
                            text: value.name,
                            value: value.uuid,
                        };
                        this.$refs.[`Blist${index}`][0].items.push(tmp);
                    });
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried, you are correct in your `//Todo: Ajax to get B list items and apply to Blist` so what have you done to achieve that?

Comment: @AJT82 what i want that is when i selected A list some value, the Blist select items will base on Alist value to change Blist options. Like selected Country then select Region relation

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But SO rules state that you need to show your effort on what you have tried. SO is not a free coding service :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Alist select and Blist select in a child component so you don't have to deal with array index. If you want the value of Blist in parent component, just emit it.

Something like:

Child Component

```
<template>
<td>
    <v-select style="width: 250px" :items="Alist" label="Purchase Order" @change="updateBlist"></v-select>
</td>
<td>
    <v-select style="width: 250px" :items="Blist" label="Group Tasks"></v-select>
</td>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        Blist: [],
        Alist: [],
    },
    methods: {
        updateBlist(value) {
            // Get Group Task List
            axios
                .get("/api/Blist/list/" + value)
                .then((resp) => {
                    this.Blist = resp.data.data.map(value=>({
                       text: value.name,
                       value: value.uuid,
                    }))
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Parent Component

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
   <ChildComponent />
</tr>
```